# cl-ncurses on SBCL

Tags: common-lisp, sbcl, quicklisp

I installed cl-ncurses through quicklisp but I am getting an error when I try to execute anything curses-based. I am not sure what is wrong but it appears that SBCL cannot find the external functions/libraries. Other curses-based programs work well in my system (Debian).

```
* (ql:quickload :cl-ncurses)
To load "cl-ncurses":
  Load 1 ASDF system:
    cl-ncurses
; Loading "cl-ncurses"

(:CL-NCURSES)
* (in-package :cl-ncurses)

#<PACKAGE "CL-NCURSES">
* (initscr)

debugger invoked on a SB-KERNEL::UNDEFINED-ALIEN-FUNCTION-ERROR in thread
#<THREAD "main thread" RUNNING {1002978CD3}>:
  Attempt to call an undefined alien function.
```

Comment: I have found an alternative ncurses binding that works for me: [cl-charms](http://http://quickdocs.org/cl-charms/api#package-CL-CHARMS)

Comment: I tried both but both return the same alien function error ... I use macOS and is that the issue.  (Brew has install the ncurses.)

Comment: Finally get it. n-curses is one thread only.  Hence it has to be the display thread you are using that access all your programs.  (If you run macOS, it would be the swank thread usually).

Answer (score 1):

The "cl-ncurses" system tries to call an undefined function of a lib (most likely libncurses.so)
Either there is a bug in the system or you use the wrong version of the lib (maybe 32 bit, while "cl-ncurses" needs 64bit)